# Is it possible to duplicate and modify the Offset command in ArtCAM 2011?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using ArtCAM Insignia 2011 build 215. I see there are Offset.htm and Offset.atext files within the HTML folder within ArtCam 2011. Is it possible to just make it offset it out a distance and then inwards a different distance without a pop up window? So basically a macro using modified HTML and Javascript of the Offset command. And secondly, how would it be possible to add this duplicate script/function/button/add-in so ArtCAM can use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To those wondering, it is possible.

Here is a link to my ArtCam forum post which contains a solution (posted by me).

> I was able to modify the Offset command and use it in ArtCAM using the Toolbox. I created a folder in ArtCAM 2011 > Toolbox. I then copied the .htm and .atext files from offset and also the images and put it in the folder I made. I renamed Offset.htm to index.htm to follow the pattern of the other examples in Toolbox. I opened index.htm and edited what I needed. After that, in ArtCAM, I opened the toolbox window (Window tab on the top > Toolbars and docking windows > Toolbox (second to last for me)) and clicked the refresh button and my add-in appeared!

[ArtCam forum link](http://forum.artcam.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=31770&p=104215#p104215)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10669917)

Comment: I don't want to post too much outside of the forums because of Dillon's response regarding ArtCam source code: It is my understanding that all of the ArtCAM source code is the property of Autodesk Delcam, and has a copyright. Other forum members have been working on their own custom Toolbox add-ins, but they do not share them outside of the Verified ArtCAM Users areas of the forum; this is intended to prevent users of illegal unlicensed ArtCAM software acquiring them.